# Would a decent powerline connection be sufficient for streaming pc hdmi over ip?

Tags: networking, ethernet, hdmi, powerline-networking

Edit: A couple notes

I'm looking into RDP/VNC alternatives for streaming my computer HDMI (and possibly its USB peripherals) to multiple TVs in rooms separate from my PC room. My goal is to find a solution that offers low latency and direct connections (PoE, HDMI wired, etc.) while sacrificing a bit of video quality, so streaming over LAN WiFi or Ethernet isn't exactly ideal. It would also be nice to directly connect my Xbox HDMI to a separate TV, since the current Xbox streaming app has to much latency for me to game on.

After a bit of research, the method I've found most viable is HDMI + USB over IP 
[HDMI KVM USB Over IP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RLRPHGH). From what I seen so far on various forum posts and a couple YouTube videos, these types of devices work well over cat5e/cat6 wired connections with a gigabit switch or two, however, I wasn't able to figure out  whether or not replacing the Ethernet wires with a powerline connection would work (the place where I live doesn't have built in Ethernet). I assume as long as a I use a gigabit adapter on the same power circuit with minimal interference, it should theoretically work just fine, right?

PC/HDMI Source ==> PoE Transmitter ==> Powerline Adapter ==> Powerline Adapter(s) ==> PoE Receiver(s) ==> TV HDMI In

Yet I'm skeptical that such a configuration will meet my expectations. I'm willing to buy the necessary equipment on amazon and return it if the setup backfires, however, since delivery times have been prolonged by the virus, I'd like a bit of reassurance before I go through with it. If all else fails, I could always fallback to VNC and use a couple RPis as receivers.

Comment: If power lines could handle the *bandwidth* of HDMI, you wouldn't need HDMI cables.

Comment: Powerline adapters are good solutions for Ethernet connectivity where running wires isn't optimal... It is better than WiFi in most cases, but not as good as a 1Gb/s Ethernet connection. It does induce some inherent delay as you can almost think of it as point to point type DSL link (it's not DSL, but it's concept is similar over a different medium). It doesn't give you a copper connection from A to B, it gives you a Layer 1 & 2 connection for Ethernet and IP connectivity. Really good ones could probably handle it, but be prepared to dish out a few hundred bucks for a pair.